# Inconsistency in the parent process id after fork call?

Tags: c, unix, process, operating-system

I am creating a small process tree and printing process id, parent process id,
process group id and process session id

```
            A(g1,s1) 

           / \

  (g1,s1)B     C (g2,s1)
```

(g,s) : (process group id, process session id)

**Problem**: In `process C`, the `output of parent process id` changes, it should display ppid as pid of process A but its not. Also `something it prints the correct output.` Why this `inconsistency in the output` ?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int err= EXIT_SUCCESS;
    pid_t process_id_A;
    pid_t process_id_B;
    pid_t process_id_C;

    /* Currently process A */
    process_id_A = getpid();
    printf("Process A: pid: %ld ppid: %ld gid: %ld sid: %ld \n",(long)getpid(),(long)getppid(),(long)getpgrp(),(long)getsid(0));

    /* Create process B */
    process_id_B= fork();
    switch(process_id_B)
    {
    case 0:
        /* Inside process B */
        //do nothing , ie same process group id and session id as process A
        printf("Process B: pid: %ld ppid: %ld gid: %ld sid: %ld \n",(long)getpid(),(long)getppid(),(long)getpgrp(),(long)getsid(0));
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    /* Create process C */
    //check if process is A , then create process C as child of A
    if(getpid() == process_id_A)
    {
        process_id_C = fork();
        switch(process_id_C)
        {
        case 0:
            /* Inside process C */

            /* Change process group id */
            err = setpgid(0,0);
            if(err == -1)
            {
                perror("setpgid() error");
                goto exit;
            }
            printf("Process C: pid: %ld ppid: %ld gid: %ld sid: %ld \n",(long)getpid(),(long)getppid(),(long)getpgrp(),(long)getsid(0));
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    exit:
        return err;
}
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./setpgid_demo.o  (1st run: correct output)
Process A: pid: 14224 ppid: 13562 gid: 14224 sid: 13562
Process B: pid: 14225 ppid: 14224 gid: 14224 sid: 13562 
Process C: pid: 14226 ppid: 14224 gid: 14226 sid: 13562 

$ ./setpgid_demo.o  (2nd run : Incorrect output)
Process A: pid: 14227 ppid: 13562 gid: 14227 sid: 13562 
Process B: pid: 14228 ppid: 14227 gid: 14227 sid: 13562 
Process C: pid: 14229 ppid: 3221 gid: 14229 sid: 13562
```

Comment: Your parent process isn’t waiting for the children.  But if that was an issue, I’d expect the PPID to be 1, not 3221.  Have you identified process 3221?   Is there one?  What happens on the third and fourth (and …) runs?

Comment: Does making the parent wait for its children change things?  Which Unix variant are you on?  What version? Anything unusual about your setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took your code and only replaced `int main(int argc, char **argv)` with `int main(void)` (since my default compiling options complain about unused variables and stop code compiling), and it then compiled cleanly (well done; I usually have to do more work than that to get code to compile cleanly for me).  And, when I ran it (it was called `pgid37`), I got the result:

```
$ ./pgid37
Process A: pid: 27489 ppid: 742 gid: 27489 sid: 740 
Process B: pid: 27490 ppid: 27489 gid: 27489 sid: 740 
Process C: pid: 27491 ppid: 1 gid: 27491 sid: 740 
$
```

Note that the parent PID (PPID) of C is 1, not 27489.  Since the A process doesn't wait for either B or C to exit, this is not surprising to me.

- I don't have a good (or even a bad) explanation for the PPID of 3321 that you saw on one occasion.

Here's a modified version of your code where the parent waits for the children — the source was in `pgid11.c` and the program was called `pgid11`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void report_ids(const char *tag)
{
    printf("Process %s: pid: %ld ppid: %ld gid: %ld sid: %ld \n",
           tag, (long)getpid(), (long)getppid(), (long)getpgrp(), (long)getsid(0));
}

int main(void)
{
    /* Currently process A */
    report_ids("A");

    /* Create process B */
    pid_t process_id_B = fork();
    if (process_id_B == 0)
    {
        report_ids("B");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    pid_t process_id_C = fork();
    if (process_id_C == 0)
    {
        /* Change process group id */
        if (setpgid(0, 0) == -1)
        {
            perror("setpgid() error");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        report_ids("C");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    int corpse;
    int status;
    while ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
    {
        printf("%d: PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n",
               (int)getpid(), corpse, status);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

One sample run gave me:

```
$ ./pgid11
Process A: pid: 27527 ppid: 742 gid: 27527 sid: 740 
Process B: pid: 27528 ppid: 27527 gid: 27527 sid: 740 
27527: PID 27528 exited with status 0x0000
Process C: pid: 27529 ppid: 27527 gid: 27529 sid: 740 
27527: PID 27529 exited with status 0x0000
$
```

This time, both children report PPID equal to the first process, 27527, which is very much what would be expected.